# Retrieve records from multiple levels of has_many relationships in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, many-to-many, rails-activerecord

Organization has many Project. Project has many websites. How do I get all websites for a particular organization with Rails 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve all websites using:

```
@websites = Website.includes(:project => :organizations).where(["organization.id = ?", params[:organization]])
```

Make sure `params[:organization]` is the actual ID of the organization of which you want to fetch all the websites for.

You can also use a [has_many :through association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association). That way, you will be able to get all websites with a simple `@organization.websites`.

> A has_many :through association is often used to set up a many-to-many
>   connection with another model. This association indicates that the
>   declaring model can be matched with zero or more instances of another
>   model by proceeding through a third model. For example, consider a
>   medical practice where patients make appointments to see physicians.
>   The relevant association declarations could look like this: